# "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in." (GstURIDecodeBin)

Tags: c, gstreamer

I have: gstreamer-sdk, gstreamer-ffmpeg, gstreamer-plugins-good, bad, and ugly. I googled everywhere for this error and have found nothing relevant. I'm going a little nuts trying to figure out this error:

```
Error received from element decodebin20: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Debugging information: gstdecodebin2.c(3576): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20:
no suitable plugins found
```

It throws when I run my gstreamer program. Any ideas on why?

Comment: What operating system are you using? How did you install those packages? Do you have anything weird in your environment (`.bashrc` for example)?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be missing any plugins at all.

This error can be a result of just an unlinked pipeline.

Playbin2(decodebin2) got some changes that made it unable to automatically link up some pipelines that formally worked, for example transcoding a decoder to an encoder.  In my case, explicitly adding the ffdec_h264 that it used to add automatically fixed it.

Relying on the Playbin2 can be very frustrating when it does not work. Using the setup below, you can create a .png diagram of the pipeline in various phases of construction. It's very helpful in finding why it isn't linking up.

`export GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=~/gstdump`

`for f in $GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR/*.dot ; do  dot -T png $f >$f.png; done`

This tool also lets you learn from it how to link up pipelines, and replace them with explicit ones that are easier to debug and less likely to break.

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora, I resolved this issue removing `gstreamer1-vaapi.x86_64`:

```
sudo yum remove gstreamer1-vaapi.x86_64
```

Comment: In Ubuntu, After installing, sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-vaapi, the same error occurred to me. I resolved by re-installing sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base and once again sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-vaapi

Answer (score 0):

1. Pleas try to use `gst-inspect` command to find out if environment is correctly setup.
2. use `gst-launch -v playbin2 uri = "your_uri_here"` to find more information to trace this issue.

Comment: ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "playbin2"

Answer (score 0):

[uridecodebin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-uridecodebin.html) is part of the "base" plugin set, so make sure you have `gstreamer-plugins-base`.

Another thing to look into is your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `GST_PLUGIN_PATH`. If they point to a different GStreamer installation, it could cause problems like this. Also, if you didn't install GStreamer with a package manager, you may need to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to it (or better yet, install it with a package manager).

Comment: Which files should I look for to make sure LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the correct directory?